# Time (second) difference commands in unix script

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, ksh

I want to find second difference with KornShell (ksh) or Bourne-again shell (Bash) in UNIX?

How can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean in time of execution?

Comment: Wouldn't `time command` do the trick?

Comment: Get the current time and substract it. If you can't find out how to do it please ask a more concrete question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking something like to calculate time taken to do something then take a look at the script below

```
#!/bin/bash
STARTING_TIME=$(date +%s)
# do something
ENDING_TIME=$(date +%s)
DIFFERENCE=$(( $ENDING_TIME - $STARTING_TIME ))
echo "It took $DIFFERENCE seconds"
```

Comment: given an error below such as:bash: %s - %s : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "%s - %s ")

Comment: @oisleyen, this `date +%s` should print a number (seconds since 1970).  Does it do this?

Comment: It should be working fine. Did you try what @Alfe has asked ?